# Using R, calculate Date of Birth by subtracting age (in years to 2SD) from an event

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe that gives me each unique individuals age in years (to 2 decimal places) on the date of an event:

```
id                eventDate              ageatEvent
1                 10-Jun-90                  44.07
2                 15-Feb-91                  30.45
3                 20-Dec-93                  59.43
4                 13-Nov-93                  45.84
5                 26-Jul-95                  25.94
6                 10-Mar-99                  21.97
7                 20-Jun-05                  32.28
8                 31-Jan-96                  48.82
```

Using R, I would like to calculate each individual's date of birth (as precise as is possible given the data).
I have tried using lubridate but it is unclear what I should be converting the numeric 'age' column into, in order to subtract from the POSIXct instant eventDate.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The easy way out of this is to not store your data as age at the time of event.

Comment: Fractional years does not even make sense to me, because the number of days in each month is not fixed.  You should tell us how this number was derived.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `lubridate` package.

`dmy` converts characters to date using the order day-month-year. `dyear`converts numeric to duration in years.

The difference gives the result.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df  <- tribble( 
~id, ~eventDate, ~ageatEvent,
1, "10-Jun-90", 44.07,

2, "15-Feb-91", 30.45,

3, "20-Dec-93", 59.43)

df <- df %>%  
  mutate(eventDate = dmy(eventDate), ageatEvent = dyears(ageatEvent)) %>% 
  mutate(dateOfBirth = eventDate - ageatEvent)
```